# Area under the curve and manual calculation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Imagine a situation where each additional item is sold with a higher price.

First Item costs 1 dollar, second item costs 2 dollars, third 3 dollars etc.

**This image show the example graph:**

[image]

If you want to buy 3 items, you would have to pay $\$1 + \$2 + \$3 = \$6$.

The area under the curve is the area of the triangle:

$$\frac12  bh = 4.5.$$

Shouldn’t the area under the graph curve equal $6$ dollars instead of $4.5$ dollars?

Clearly I’m not getting something right here.

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: The area under the graph from $0$ to $1$ is $1/2$, which is $1/2$ dollar short.  The area under the graph from $1$ to $2$ is $3/2$, which is $1/2$ dollar short.  The area under the graph from $2$ to $3$ is $5/2$, which is $1/2$ dollar short.  Apparently you need the line to be shifted up a bit if you want its areas over these unit intervals to equal each of the three item costs...  (... or add $1/2$ dollars per item to make up for this shortfall ...)

Comment: So basically I'm looking for a formula to help me calculate how much the customer has to pay for requested number of items with constant increasing price.. I thought integration solves this problem, or in this case geometric formula since the graph is linear. I still don't get why is it short for 1/2 dollar ...

Comment: Look at your graph between $0$ and $1$.  The area for one itsm's cost is the $1 \times 1$ square in your graph, the lower-right half of which is the blue triangle your integral is giving you.  So you have graphed why the integral is $1/2$ dollar short on $[0,1]$.  On $[1,2]$ you want an area that is the same as two $1 \times 1$ blocks stacked on top of each other, but your function has cut off the upper-left half of the upper block...

Answer (score 1):

For easier reading, I shall refer to the items as pens.

1. Consider labelling the axes better: the vertical axis "cost" is very
   ambiguous (total cost? average cost? etc.?) and can be renamed "cost
   of the $n$th pen", while the horizontal axis should be "pen
   number/index" instead of "number of pens".
2. The area under a graph gives the sum of the 'vertical' quantity as
   the function varies over an *interval* of the 'horizontal' quantity.
   On the other hand, the pens' total cost is a sum of *discretely*
   many items, rather than a sum over an interval. This is why they aren't
   equal.
3. The sum that you require is just an arithmetic series, so does have
   a formula: $$\text{total cost of $n$ pens}=\frac{n(n+1)}2.$$
4. Reverse-engineering this formula: $$\text{total cost of $n$ pens}\\=\text{the area under the $\left(x+\frac12\right)$-versus-$x$ graph between $0$ and $n$}.$$